# Flexbox? Only use left half of screen on desktop but full screen on mobile for a personal blog site

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm part way through a tutorial on Udemy for web dev, while simultaneously building a personal blog hosting on GitHub.

To make the text easier to read I would like to only use the left half of the screen on desktop, and the entire screen on mobile for all my pages.

What is the easiest way to do this?

So far I have just used html and JS for the page, and I think the solution involves CSS/Flexbox but not sure where to start.

Comment: Hey @SSD...you're going to need to take a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Media queries, or use bootstrap if you are a beginner as it will ease your work

Comment: Thank you @psdpainter I learnt about media queries and bootstrap and solved it with this:

media (min-width: 420px){
    .container {
      max-width: 420px;
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the issues, I ended up solving it with:

```
@media (min-width: 420px){
.container {
  max-width: 420px;
}
```

}

Decided this was the most aesthetic and easy to read width.